# Typescript: how to correctly do type inference in union types?

Tags: typescript, union-types

I defined a union type called `IConfigFactory`, it accepts a parameter of type `IConfig` or returns a function of type `IConfig`。

but it not do type inference correctly, like as follows:

```
interface IViteConfig {
  vite?: true;
}

interface IWebpackConfig {
  vite?: false;
  plugins: string[];
}

type IConfig = IViteConfig | IWebpackConfig;

type IConfigFactory = (() => IConfig) | IConfig;

function defineConfig(config: IConfigFactory) {
  return config;
}

defineConfig({
  vite: true,   // Not prompting as expected
  plugins: [],
});

type IConfigFactory2 = IConfig;

function defineConfig2(config: IConfigFactory2) {
  return config;
}

defineConfig2({
  vite: true,
  plugins: [], // Prompting as expected
});
```

[image]

[image]

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDViQMIHsQzADmyA3gFDLIBuWEA-AFzJhQCuEA3OQL7nmhIsRClQB1CACMADogDWeAsTKUadJsngAbAM5dV0rWyKgdzHa1BEA2gF1ufcmACe00YsIkAvGkw58nsgAPmgSMvIexNxOru4BxABiiGC4UM7IPgAUmQCUGQB8aJFEeSGoxdEwbCAIYMD4yAAmEIQgEMWZCPFEzOXdSbWpznkUVFAQYGxQIMhdSkQO-M2t7d2Zo2qQzKwcADRUyAD0h8gAcrhgyNJQuAC20nUgJHA6yBAAHm61EI0GRiYgMzIOy7Xg5aIuNxFfrJIYAJgy0PmlWqtXqM2WoFW8zhnW6vWKAxSaThI1U40m01m3UW5ExbWKuI2tC2LHYEFBVEMxlMzBBRxOAAUbvdHs9Xh8vpBfjxweQgA)

but when I defined `IConfigFactory` only accepts a parameter of type `IConfig`, it works well.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it？

Comment: what do you mean by `Not prompting as expected`? Error? I did see a red line under it

Comment: @Eldar boolean (and even number) works fine as a discriminant property type.

Comment: discriminated unions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

Answer (score 1):

##### Edit

Based on comments, use an explicit discriminator rather than relying on `vite` being true or false. If you think about it, that approach is fragile anyway, as it defines all config in terms of vite. Maybe you want to add Rollup or Tsup, etc.

```js
interface ViteConfig {
  kind: 'vite'
}

interface WebpackConfig {
  kind: 'webpack'
  plugins: string[]
}
```

Result:
[image]

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGrEgYQPYhsAc2QG8AoZZAa1ABMAuZAcgDcMJHSBfU00SWRCgDqEAEYAHRJRx5CJclVoNGAdzGSElDhXEAbAK4FQAZwbGwUUAQDaAXS48wAT3EoZ%20IgF40bd3IA%20yCISUn4Eji5uuB4AYohg2FBOyN4AFKkAlCkAfMhhWYFhPDD6IAhgwLjINBD4IBBhqQjRhAxhceWJTllkFFAQYPpQIMjNsgQA3A6kNXUNLQSpxIog9EyskIzInBkTFPsHh8gA9MfI2JQ8s6Dz40srayxsjAA0yHqGJgx227sUp6NsABbPRwEyAqD9cq6ZJwUTYfRgZAbCCkIA)

##### Original

TypeScript discriminated unions work by being specific about a 'discriminator'. In your case, `vite`:

```js
interface IViteConfig {
  vite: true;                  // <--- NOTE
}

interface IWebpackConfig {
  vite: false;                 // <--- NOTE
  plugins: string[];
}

type IConfig = IViteConfig | IWebpackConfig;

type IConfigFactory = (() => IConfig) | IConfig;

function defineConfig(config: IConfigFactory) {
  return config;
}

defineConfig({ vite: true });               // ok

defineConfig({ vite: false, plugins: [] }); // ok
```

([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDViQMIHsQzADmyA3gFDLIBuWEAXMmFAK4QDc5AvueaJLEQpUAdQgAjAA6IA1ngLEylGnUbwANgGcOyyepZFQmxpuagiAbQC6nHuTABPScPmESAXjSYc%20N8gA%20aGJSsq7EnPZOLr7EAGKIYLhQDsieABRpAJSpAHxoYUTZgagFETAsIAhgwPjIACYQhCAQBWkIMUSMJR3xVUkO2RRUUBBgLFAgyO0KRLa8DU0tHWmkKpCMzGzIXJnsVPsHh8gA9MfIuDLzjaBLMytrDMga2gA0yHoGRozW27snZxdyEA))

As a side note, the `I` prefix, commonly used in old school WIN32 and C#-land is overkill in TypeScript.

The same code without the `I`'s is more 'ergnomic' (though this is subjective, of course:

```js
interface ViteConfig {
  vite: true;
}

interface WebpackConfig {
  vite: false;
  plugins: string[];
}

type Config = ViteConfig | WebpackConfig;

type ConfigFactory = (() => Config) | Config;

function defineConfig(config: ConfigFactory) {
  return config;
}

defineConfig({ vite: true });               // ok

defineConfig({ vite: false, plugins: [] }); // ok
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply， but I want plugins to be underlined in red instead of vite; `defineConfig({ vite: true,  plugins: [] }); ` [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDViQMIHsQzADmyA3gFDLIBuWEAXMmFAK4QDc5AvueaJLEQpUAdQgAjAA6IA1ngLEylGnUbwANgGcOyyepZFQmxpuagiAbQC6nHuTABPScPmESAXjSYc+N8gA+aGJSsq7EnPZOLr7EAGKIYLhQDsieABRpAJSpAHxoYUTZgagFETAsIAhgwPjIACYQhCAQBWkIMUSMJR3xVUkO2RRUUBBgLFAgyO0KRLa8DU0tHWmkKpCMzGwANFR6BkaM1shcmezIvEA)

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you mean, but I think you're saying you want to be o o ifude (in this css) just plugins and you want typescript to figure out that bite SHOULD be false.

Comment: If so move away from vite being the discriminate. Make a new "kind" field and set it to "bite" | "webpack". I can update the code if you'd like.